# Google app engine: IOException thrown while closing Closeable

Tags: java, google-app-engine, blob

I am trying to upload a Mp3 file using blobstore. But the problem is that when I upload the file with size more than 2 or 3 mb.  It throws an IOException thrown while closing Closeable. It dosen't really affect any fuctionality. But can anyone help me to find what is this exception??

I am appending the exception details below.

```
com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:98)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:491)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:547)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
        at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
        at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:51)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:51)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:487)
        at org.mortbay.io.nio.ChannelEndPoint.flush(ChannelEndPoint.java:169)
        at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.flush(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:221)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpGenerator.flush(HttpGenerator.java:721)
        ... 31 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working. I am adding my code below

```
public void getUploaded(@PathVariable String key, HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res, HttpSession session) throws IOException {
        try {
            BlobKey blobKey = new BlobKey(key);
            BlobInfo blobInfo =  new BlobInfoFactory().loadBlobInfo(blobKey);
            OutputStream output = res.getOutputStream();

            InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(readData(blobKey,blobInfo.getSize()));

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length = is.read(buffer)) > 0)
                output.write(buffer, 0, length);
            is.close();
            output.flush();
            output.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public byte[] readData(BlobKey blobKey, long blobSize) {
        BlobstoreService blobStoreService = BlobstoreServiceFactory
                .getBlobstoreService();
        byte[] allTheBytes = new byte[0];
        long amountLeftToRead = blobSize;
        long startIndex = 0;
        while (amountLeftToRead > 0) {
            long amountToReadNow = Math.min(
                    BlobstoreService.MAX_BLOB_FETCH_SIZE - 1, amountLeftToRead);

            byte[] chunkOfBytes = blobStoreService.fetchData(blobKey,
                    startIndex, startIndex + amountToReadNow - 1);

            allTheBytes = ArrayUtils.addAll(allTheBytes, chunkOfBytes);

            amountLeftToRead -= amountToReadNow;
            startIndex += amountToReadNow;
        }

        return allTheBytes;
    }
```